# How to keep url intact while changing the rendered page in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

The routine way of rendering a different page is by calling a url `/this` from the html which is trapped by `app.get('/this'...` which renders the new page.

I want to keep the url intact, so i call from 'http://abc.com' and a new page is rendered while the url doesn't change.

Comment: Can you clarify using more precise technical terminology? What have you tried so far? What is your broader goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can make your route handler as dynamic as you want:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    //here you can render a different page based on whatever
    //such as the referer header
    //what day of the week it is
    //a random page, whatever
});
```

If by "called from" you mean the user clicks a link to your site on the page at 'http://abc.com', the request your express app receives will have abc.com as the `Referer` header in `req.get('Referer')`, so you could use that value to render a dynamic response but the URL in the browser would remain 'yoursite.example/'.